# How to create user-friendly and seo-friendly urls in jsf?

Tags: jsp, jsf, friendly-url, front-controller

For example, I have class Article with methods `getTitle ()` and `getContent ()`.

I also have ArticlesService with method `getAllArticles ()`. How to create a list of links with meaningful names (formed with `#{article.title}`)? Like:

```
http://mysiteaddress.com/article/first-article-title
http://mysiteaddress.com/article/how-to-make-links-in-jsf
```

..or something similar.

I can create links with all necessary functionality with `<h:commandLink>`, but I don't know how to make nice 'href' for it: it always has href '#'.

I can create nice links with `<h:outputLink>` but I don't know how to add necessary functionality to it.

---

In jsp I created my own front-controller, which parsed urls from requests and then performed redirection to correspondent jsp-page.

How to achieve the same functionality in JSF?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is intended as an improvement of an existing application, then you basically need a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which detects "dirty" and "friendly" URLs. When it detects a "dirty" URL, then it should *redirect* the request to a "friendly" URL by [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29). When it detects a "friendly" URL, then it should *forward* the request to the "dirty" URL by [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29). An example can be found in this related question: [How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)

Further, you also need a custom [`ViewHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html) to produce the desired "friendly" URL for JSF `<h:form>`, `<h:link>`, etc. An example can be found here: [Dynamic Directory in Java EE Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408703/dynamic-directory-in-java-ee-web-application).

If this is a new application or an application which is open to changes, you could consider any of the existing pretty URL libraries instead of reinventing the wheel:

- [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/), which is a complete URL rewrite solution. It requires an additional XML configuration file `pretty-config.xml`. This library is useful if you want to completely change URLs and/or want to configure redirects from old to new URLs.
- [FacesViews](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs) of [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) library, which makes existing URLs just extensionless by a single `web.xml` context param. It also supports "MultiViews" whereby path parameters can declaratively be injected in managed beans. E.g. `/foo/bar/baz` can point to `/foo.xhtml` and the values `bar` and `baz` can be injected by `@Param(pathIndex)`.

There's also the experimental [PrettyUrlPhaseListener](http://kenai.com/projects/scales/pages/PrettyUrlPhaseListener) of [Mojarra Scales](http://kenai.com/projects/scales/pages/Home) library, but it's an old library and PrettyFaces is largely based on it, so it's not worth the effort.

Comment: what if i do not have friendly url physically. I have all posts present in database like stackoverflow. Then how to create url in JSF.

Comment: What about performance and round trips when using prettyfaces?

Comment: @pipalia Measuring is knowing.

Comment: @BalusC Just asking since we are dumping JSF completely due to these kind of performance and other well known issues with this rigid architecture.

Answer (score 8):

Did you tried [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/)?

### Simple, effective, bookmark, JSF

PrettyFaces is an OpenSource extension for JSF1.2 and JSF2.0, which enables creation of bookmark-able, pretty URLs. PrettyFaces solves this problem elegantly, including features such as: page-load actions, seamless integration with faces navigation, dynamic view-id assignment, managed parameter parsing, and configuration-free compatibility with other JSF frameworks.

### SEO and Consistency:

Any business knows how important Search Engine Optimization can be for sales. PrettyFaces allows SEO-friendly URLs, and improved customer experience. Give your site a uniform, well understood feeling, from the address bar to the buy button.

Comment: I tried but no work for me... I created a new project in NetBeans 7.3, then I added the PF 3.3.3 jar file to library, and edit web.xml and add the PF xml (config) as well... but only work the mappings of PF config

Comment: Never mind, I used now `OmniFaces` (with similar problem), but I solved by change the stage from `Development` to `Production`