# p:dataTable filter/sort functions not working inside p:carousel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have created a `<p:dialog>` with an embedded `<p:carousel>` with `tabs` and in one of the tabs I have a `<p:datatable>` but I am noticing that actions like `Pagination`, `Filtering` and `Sorting` do not work in my datatable when the datatable is inside a `carousel` component (I tried to remove the carousel and the actions work perfectly). Are there any known issues concerning the compatibility of `carousel` and `datatable` components? Am I doing something wrong?

**.xhtml code**

```
 <p:dialog header="View information"
           widgetVar="dialog" id="dialog"
           position="center" modal="true" height="300" width="400"
           appendTo="@(body)">
           <p:carousel id="carousel" widgetVar="carousel" circular="true" numVisible="1" itemStyle="width:500px;height:400px;" pageLinks="1"> 
            <p:tab>
               <h:form prependId="false">
                 <p:dataTable id="carousel_results" var="obj"
                                            value="#{myBean.myModel.myObjects}"
                                            widgetVar="carouselTable"
                                            rowKey="#{obj.value}"
                                            paginator="true" rows="10"
                                            filteredValue="#{myBean.filteredObjects}"
                                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,100,{ShowAll|'Show All'" paginatorPosition="bottom">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            Information 
                                        </f:facet>
              <p:column headerText="Value" filterBy="#{obj.value}"
                         filterValue="#{obj.value}"
                         filterMatchMode="contains"
                         sortBy="#{obj.value}">                
                        <h:outputText value="{obj.value}"/>
              </p:column>       

               ........


            </p:dataTable>
          </h:form>
       </p:tab>
    </p:carousel>
</p:dialog>
```

**MyBean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
private Model myModel
private List<CustomObject> filteredObjects // list to store filtered objects
```

**Model**

```
 public class Model{
    private List<CustomObject> myObjects
 }
```

I am using Primefaces version 7.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create user-friendly and seo-friendly urls in jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921168/how-to-create-user-friendly-and-seo-friendly-urls-in-jsf)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, how a custom webfilter could resolve this problem? Could you give me more details please?

Comment: Doesn't a datatable inside a Carousel seem like a bad UI design?  I would love to know your use case?

Comment: Well i have a datatable of selectable objects with a "View" option. These objects contain 3 different lists of other objects. When a user clicks to "view" more information in first datatable for an object, a carousel of 3 tabs (each tab containing a datatable of each list of objects) will be shown, using a separate datatable, is it so bad as it sounds? Could you suggest any other way?? :) thanks